# Breaking nested dictionary into list

Tags: python

I have been handling data from graph theory lately. I need to reiterate the shortest path in a form of nested dictionary to a tuple of lists.

For example:

What I received:

`{0:{2:{4:{},3:{}}},1:{2:{2:{},7:{}}}}`

What I want:

`[[4,2,0],[3,2,0],[2,2,1],[7,2,1]]`

My first thought was to define a function to append the list. However, I have been struggling from that for several hours already. I have no clue to get into the deepest keys of the dictionary…

Look forward to hearing advice from you guys, really appreciate of your help!!!

(P.s I have the number of layers of the nest, such as 3 for the above example)

Comment: I'm struggling to understand how you are getting from one to the other. I see all those same numbers in the two, but the pattern is eluding me. Can you explain the logic to get from nested dictionary to a list of lists?

Comment: @JNevill they're going from each leaf node (the deepest level) and tracing the paths to the root nodes, so since the first part of the dict is `0 -> 2 -> (4, 3)`, they get the lists `[3, 2, 0]` and `[4, 2, 0]`

Comment: Oh!  oh! Yeah that makes sense. Thanks

Comment: @JNevill The process is to start from the most inner layer (the empty sub dictionary), and then get back to the outer ones, one by one

Comment: What have you tried? You should show the attempt that got you closest and ask a specific question about a problem you encountered with that. Traversing trees is covered pretty well in lots of online resources. What _specifically_ did you struggle with?

Comment: Are there any ways to draw out the deepest layer just by knowing the number of layers?  My thought is to use for i in dictionary, and then for item in i, so on and so forth…

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I am sorry, this is the first time I ask question

Comment: You probably want to take a look at recursive functions that will drill down into a dictionary. If you encounter a dictionary that isn't empty, find the path to the leaf nodes of _that_ dictionary, and then append that list to the current path

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Thank you for your advice, I will start from this direction first!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A recursive approach works for this. Define a function that will return the path to the nodes in your dictionary like so:

1. For each item in the dictionary

   - if the item is not a dictionary, or an empty dictionary, we yield its key.
   - if the item is a non-empty dictionary, we get the path to the children of this item, and append the item's key to this path before yielding.

```
def dict_keys_to_list(d):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict) and v:
            for c in dict_keys_to_list(v):
                yield c + [k]
        else:
            yield [k]
```

To use this:

```
d = {0:{2:{4:{},3:{}}},1:{2:{2:{},7:{}}}}
x = list(dict_keys_to_list(d))
print(x)
```

gives:

```
[[4, 2, 0], [3, 2, 0], [2, 2, 1], [7, 2, 1]]
```

Comment: Interestingly, Pranav and I have a different recursive approach. This one retrieves the values back up in the recursive calls to yield them, while mine pushes the values down for the last branch to yield them ;)

Comment: The order of the items in the output seems however incorrect

Comment: @FletcherNg here's some more information about `yield`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/231767/843953 Look up the docs for any funcions you don't know, and feel free to add a comment if you have questions.

Comment: I took the liberty to fix the code ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive generator:

```
def unnest(d, val=[]):
    if d == {}:
        yield val
    else:
        for k,v in d.items():
            yield from unnest(v, [k]+val)
            
list(unnest(d))
```

Output:

```
[[4, 2, 0], [3, 2, 0], [2, 2, 1], [7, 2, 1]]
```

How it works:

- for each key, value pair, run a recursive iteration on the sub dictionaries passing the key as parameter.
- at each step the new key is added on front of the list
- when an empty dictionary is found the path is over, yield the list